# How to exceute a query stored in dictionary table into a CURSOR?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I’ve a table named QUERIES_DICTIONNARY with 2 columns (ID, SQL_QUERY) the first column is NUMBER and the second column is a Varchar represent an SQL query.

```
CREATE TABLE "QUERIES_DICTIONNARY" 
(
    "ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SQL_QUERY" NVARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL ENABLE
)
```

I want to create a stored procedure with 2 parameters (P_KEY, P_RESULTS_CURSOR) where the P_KEY is the ID of my table, and the P_RESULT_CURSOR where i execute my SQL query of the record having ID = P_KEY.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_STATISTICS_RESULTS 
(
    P_KEY IN NUMBER,
    P_RESULTS_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
)
```

In my stored procedure I get the record where the ID = P_KEY 
Once I’ve the record I want to execute the the associated query using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE into the P_RESULTS_CURSOR.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_STATISTICS_RESULTS 
(
    P_KEY IN NUMBER
    P_RESULTS_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
) AS 
    BEGIN
        ---- Get the record
        -- SELECT SQL_QUERY FROM QUERIES_DICTIONNARY WHERE ID = P_KEY; 
        ---- Then Execute the query
        -- OPEN P_RESULTS_CURSOR FOR ? 

    END GET_STATISTICS_RESULTS;
```

How can I do this approach in one Stored procedure please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways: simple and not so simple. Simple way is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_STATISTICS_RESULTS 
(
P_KEY IN NUMBER;
P_RESULTS_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR;
) AS 
cursor_text QUERIES_DICTIONNARY.SQL_QUERY%TYPE; 
BEGIN
    ---- Get the record
    SELECT SQL_QUERY 
    INTO cursor_text
    FROM QUERIES_DICTIONNARY WHERE ID = P_KEY; 
    ---- Then Execute the query
    OPEN P_RESULTS_CURSOR FOR cursor_text;

END GET_STATISTICS_RESULTS;
```

Not so simple way - using [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm) package. You can see example in documentation. It will be quite complicated decision.

Comment: I get an error on line OPEN P_RESULTS_CURSOR FOR cursor_text; 
ERROR: PLS-00382: expressions is of wrong type

Comment: Hmmm. Its because of your table's field has type `NVARCHAR2`. You can convert it using `to_char`, for example. Do you really need for queries namely `NVARCHAR2`, not 'VARCHAR2'?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_STATISTICS_RESULTS 
(
    P_KEY IN NUMBER
    P_RESULTS_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
) AS 
    l_s "QUERIES_DICTIONNARY"."SQL_QUERY"%TYPE;
    BEGIN
        ---- Get the record
        SELECT SQL_QUERY into l_s FROM QUERIES_DICTIONNARY WHERE ID = P_KEY;

        ---- Then Execute the query
        OPEN P_RESULTS_CURSOR FOR l_s; 
    END GET_STATISTICS_RESULTS;
```

PLS-00382 appears because of NVARCHAR2 column. You may try to cast nvarchar2 to varchar2:

```
l_s VARCHAR2(4000);
...
SELECT CAST(SQL_QUERY AS VARCHAR2(4000)) into l_s FROM QUERIES_DICTIONNARY WHERE ID = P_KEY;
...
```

But you may lose some data.

Comment: I got an erro PLS-00382 on line OPEN P_RESULTS_CURSOR FOR l_s;

Comment: @cYounes The problem is with NVARCHAR2 I suppose. Is it mandatory to keep sqls in NVARCHAR column?

Comment: @cYounes You may cast it to varchar2 field, but some symbols (national characters) maybe converted wrongly